# Simple function using numpy won't run

Tags: python

I have been at this for more than 2 hours. Each individual line prints out the result I am looking for. However, when I run all the lines in the program, python print values or Ixx, Iyy and Ixy. Why is this?

```
import numpy as np

Ixx = 14600000
Iyy = 14600000
Ixy = 7080*(47.2-12.5)**2
alpha = 45

x = 0.5*(Ixx+Iyy)+0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.cos(2*alpha/180*np.pi)+Ixy*np.sin(2*alpha/180*np.pi)
y = 0.5*(Ixx+Iyy)-0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.cos(2*alpha/180*np.pi)-Ixy*np.sin(2*alpha/180*np.pi)
z = 0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.sin(2*alpha/180*np.pi)+Ixy*np.cos(2*alpha/180*np.pi)

print x,y,z
```

Comment: Can you save your code to a file, run it, and then take the exact output of the code and edit it into your question? I can see no reason why the behavior you describe (`Ixx`, `Iyy`, and `Ixy` being printed) would happen.

Comment: This is my output
>>> runfile('C:/Documents and Settings/Alex/Desktop/SAP/untitled3.py', wdir=r'C:/Documents and Settings/Alex/Desktop/SAP')
14600000.0 14600000.0 8524957.2

Comment: After verification, the program seems to simply be ignoring all of the rest of the equation (after the first term). Could there be a problem with the numpy module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running this under python2.x, then you are losing information with the statement `2*alpha/180*np.pi` (python3.x should work though).

The operations are evaluated in order of precedence (left to right in this case), which gives

```
((2 * alpha) / 180) * ni.pi
=> (90 / 180) * ni.pi # integer division truncates this to 0
=> 0 * ni.pi
```

You need to manually convert to a float, either:

```
np.sin(2.0*alpha/180*np.pi) # the floating point 2.0 will promote alpha to float for the multiply
```

Or

```
np.sin(2*float(alpha)/180*np.pi) # explicit, very clear
```

Or

```
alpha = 45.0 # this is a little dangerous as you might change the angle in the future and forget to make it a float again
```

Comment: Ah-ha, integer division! Great catch, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I understand why, but changing the interior of my sinus and cosinus terms solved the problem. I changed

```
x = 0.5*(Ixx+Iyy)+0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.cos(2*alpha/180*np.pi)+Ixy*np.sin(2*alpha/180*np.pi)
y = 0.5*(Ixx+Iyy)-0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.cos(2*alpha/180*np.pi)-Ixy*np.sin(2*alpha/180*np.pi)
z = 0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.sin(2*alpha/180*np.pi)+Ixy*np.cos(2*alpha/180*np.pi)
```

to

```
Ixx_a = 0.5*(Ixx+Iyy)+0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.cos(np.pi*alpha/90) + Ixy*np.sin(np.pi*alpha/90)
Iyy_a = 0.5*(Ixx+Iyy)-0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.cos(np.pi*alpha/90) - Ixy*np.sin(np.pi*alpha/90)
Ixy_a = 0.5*(Ixx-Iyy)*np.sin(np.pi*alpha/90)+Ixy*np.cos(np.pi*alpha/90)
```

which is mathematically equivalent, but apparently numpy finds it easier to compute.

Comment: Read @PeterGibson's answer to understand why.  This isn't about numpy, it's that you reordered things to put a float-like number first, so you didn't have truncating integer division.  Exactly the same thing would have happened if you used `math.pi` etc instead of `np.pi`.

Comment: "mathematically equivalent" and "computationally equivalent" are very different things ;)